# Color text for rails doesn't show up in eclipse

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eclipse, aptana3

I'm trying to get color text in, but it's just giving me black fonts white background. It's quite difficult to read.

I tried installing aptana. Nothing changed.

Comment: by "color text" do you mean "syntax highlighting"?

Comment: yes. I went to apperances -> color themes. It didn't do anything either.

Comment: and what file extension are you trying to open?  `erb`, `rb`, `haml`?  what

Comment: I've found funny little things like this using IntelliJ.  Rails appears fine on IntelliJ using a light on dark theme, but Jade will be dark purple text which is very difficult to see in a light on dark theme

Comment: Use sublime text editor.

Answer (score 0):

you have to install plugin for that. See the link:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EclipseIDE